# App crashes after I run my Higher and Lower game in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a beginner and trying to learn programming in Android studio while i got stuck in one of the problem. I know similar question has been asked before but I was curious as to why one of my methods is wrong while other one is working. So, I created a higher and Lower number guessing app and it works with using onClick method with button but not with setOnClicklistener method(It crashes on start). Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong.[image: It gives me error without declaring variables as final and after declaring them final it crashes.]

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int randomNumber;

    public void myChanger(View view) {
        EditText guessText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guessText);
        int actualguess = Integer.parseInt(guessText.getText().toString());
        if (actualguess == randomNumber) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You are Right!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(actualguess > randomNumber){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Try lower", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(actualguess < randomNumber){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Try higher", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Random random = new Random();
        randomNumber = random.nextInt(20 - 0)+ 1;
}
}
```

Both of these codes worked for me now. Thanks for the help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText guessText = findViewById(R.id.guessText);
    Button guessButton = findViewById(R.id.guessButton);
    Random random = new Random();
    final int randomNumber = random.nextInt(20) + 1;
    guessButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int guessNum = Integer.parseInt(guessText.getText().toString());
            if (guessNum == randomNumber){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (guessNum > randomNumber){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Try lower Value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (guessNum < randomNumber){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Try Higher Value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Add all code in a text, not in the image. Also, add logcat. It will be easier to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
EditText guessText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guessText);
String guessString = guessText.getText().toString();
final int numguess = Integer.parseInt(guessString);
```

You have written these lines in `onCreate`. When `onCreate` is called there is no text in `guessText`, so `guessString` will be equal to`""`. Then when you try to parse this String to integer you get `NumberFormatException`. That is the reason.

All you have to do is writing these two lines:

```
String guessString = guessText.getText().toString();
final int numguess = Integer.parseInt(guessString);
```

inside `onClickListener` right before `if-else` block. I would also recommend, before parsing string to Integer, check if it is not empty (not equal to "").

Last two things:

1. Add your code in text not in image.
2. If you get error share the logcat.

Comment: Yup,it worked thanks for the help and the tip about posting code in text will keep that in mind in future.